# How to set picklist value using workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I'm creating a lead record using import function (System->Data Management-> Import), I have creatd a workflow for once the lead record is created, the contact record field 'Salutation' which is a dropdown list must be updated.

When I'm trying to do this, looking for lead doesn't appear to have any value coming on it. Don't know how to set picklist value for updating records using workflow. Please see the screnshot below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That seems odd, you should get all available options when updating a record with a workflow. Is the picklist populated with values? The salutation dropdown is not a standard field in CRM 4.0, it's a freetext field OOB.

Regards

Comment: This is a problem in CRM we can't set the Pick-list value with mapping  from another entity. I.e. setting the salutation pick-list value from Lead to contact can not be done.

Comment: Try to make sure that both picklists has the same ids for the options. You don't set a picklist to the string label, you set it to the id of the string label.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing pick-list field value can be set dynamically on a record by the field of another entity.
 What I did I check multiple cases and update the field manually to achieve this. 
i.e. If lead(car1) == 2 update the pick-list value on workflow with your choice. But this is q dirty fix because conditions are more and is difficult to use multiple times for updating record.